# Backbone Model Set Attribute on Drop Event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

This may be due to the fact that I'm new to JavaScript, and I just don't know the correct syntax, but I can't get my backbone model attributes to set on this Drop Event with this current syntax.  Any suggestions?  I've ran some tests with the `handleDrop` already and been able to set and save the model instance, but not with this current code in the `handleDrop` function.

Other suggestions regarding more efficient ways of writing this are always welcome :)

```
        //Set the data contained by the draggable elements
        var sourceID;
        var payloads = {
            poolpricedraggable: "poolprice",
            nonedraggable: "none"
        };

        //Set the data contained in the droppable elements
        var targetID;
        var targets = {
            panelone: "panel_one:",
            paneltwo: "panel_two:",
            panelthree: "panel_three:",
            panelfour: "panel_four:",
            panelfive: "panel_five:",
            panelsix: "panel_six:"              
        }
        
        //Create variable for all draggable & droppable elements
        var element = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
        
        //Create event handlers for all drag and drop events
        function handleDragStart(event) {
            sourceID = this.id;
        }
        function handleDrop(event) {
            if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
            targetID = this.id;
            var dataattribute = targets[targetID];
            var datavalue = payloads[sourceID];
            var data = dataattribute + " " + datavalue;
          preflist.set(data);
            preflist.save();
        }
        
        //Add listeners for those events to the correct dashboard elements
        element('poolpricedraggable').addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);

        element('panelone').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        element('paneltwo').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        element('panelthree').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        element('panelfour').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        element('panelfive').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        element('panelsix').addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make the assumption that `preflist` is a Backbone Model. Your mistake happens here:

```
var data = dataattribute + " " + datavalue;
preflist.set(data);
```

The `data` variable here is a string, but the Backbone model `set` -function takes a hash of attributes as key-value pairs

> **set** model.set(attributes, [options])
>
> Set a hash of attributes (one or many) on the model...

So you should do it like this:

```
// var data = dataattribute + " " + datavalue; REMOVE THIS
var data = {};
data[dataattribute] = datavalue;
preflist.set(data);
```

**EDIT, mu is too short's comment was better**

According to Backbone.js [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set)

> You may also pass individual keys and values.

So this is a better solution, obviously:

```
preflist.set(dataattribute, datavalue);
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: You're right jakee.  Awesome!  Everything is working as it should!  For anyone using this post as a resource, I included a colon on each value in the "targets" variable which needs to be removed when following jakee's instructions.  Thanks jakee!

Comment: You could also `preflist.set(dataattribute, datavalue)` since ["you may also pass individual keys and values"](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).